# SVMs are outdated for time series classification - Citation needed

Tags: time-series, classification, references, svm, model-comparison

I'm looking for a strong publication I can cite to prove that SVMs perform worse for time series classification tasks in comparison to other methods (such as ANNs, Decision Trees, Gradient Boosting Machines, etc...).

I found several posts indicating or justifying that SVMs are not [popular nowadays](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-SVM-not-popular-nowadays-Also-when-did-SVM-perform-poorly), that [deep learning rendered kernel methods obsolete](https://www.quora.com/Has-deep-learning-rendered-kernel-methods-obsolete) or that SVMs have [severe drawbacks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/711/are-support-vector-machines-still-considered-state-of-the-art-in-their-niche) (such as parameter sensitivity or the need to conduct a grid search for the parameters).

However, I could not find a source explicitly stating that SVMs perform worse for time series classification tasks than more recent models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding

> I'm looking for a strong publication I can cite to prove that SVMs perform worse for time series classification tasks in comparison to other methods (such as ANNs, Decision Trees, Gradient Boosting Machines, etc...),

you might be seeking a reference for a claim that is not generally correct. A key thing to remember is, there is no free lunch in model selection. As Dikran Marsupian says in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57438/why-is-svm-not-so-good-as-decision-tree-on-the-same-data/57442#57442),

> the no free lunch theorems say that there is no a-priori superiority for any classifier system over the others, so the best classifier for a particular task is itself task-dependent

and adds:

> However there is more compelling theory for the SVM that suggests it is likely to be better choice than many other approaches for many problems.

I bet there exists a data generating process and a sample size for which SVM systematically beats other methods.

---

Regarding

> I found several posts indicating or justifying that SVMs are not popular nowadays, that deep learning rendered kernel methods obsolete or that SVMs have severe drawbacks (such as parameter sensitivity or the need to conduct a grid search for the parameters),

this might be true as of now. Perhaps a lot of time series that people are forecasting and writing about lend themselves more easily to those other methods. But popularity and optimality do not always go hand in hand, and the no free lunch theorem remains applicable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I agree that the no-free-lunch theorem has to be taken into account. Are you, however, at least aware of a good reference proving that "SVMs often do take a long time to train" and that the optimal parameter choice is often difficult to find as stated by Dikran Marsupial in the link you provided?

Comment: @Hagbard, I wish I had more experience with and expertise in SVMs, but I do not... Perhaps you could post your latter question as a comment under Dikran's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this might be a late answer, but I just wanted to add that you cannot simply say that SVMs are outdated for time series classification (TSC).

It rather depends on the kernel function you're using. The conventional kernels such as RBF, poly, etc. sure aren't fitting well for TSC. This is due to the time axis distortion problem

> Because of the time axis distortion problem, classical
> kernel functions, such as Gaussian RBF (GRBF) and
> polynomial, generally are not suitable for SVM-based time
> series classification. Motivated by the success of dynamic
> time wrapping (DTW) distance, it has been suggested to
> utilize elastic measure to construct appropriate kernel.

This said, if you choose a custom kernel function such as GTWED or GERP (subtypes of GEMK), SVMs show high potential in TSC:

> Experimental results show that, in terms of
> classification accuracy, SVM with GEMK is much superior
> to the state-of-the-art similarity measure methods and SVM
> with GRBF and GDTW kernels.

Source: Dongyu Zhang, Wangmeng Zuo, David Zhang, Hongzhi Zhang: Time Series Classification Using Support Vector Machine with Gaussian Elastic Metric Kernel, 2010. In: 2010 International Conference on Pattern Recognition. DOI: 10.1109/ICPR.2010.16
(https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5597650)

Comment: Hi, we are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of web links in the answers, due to link rot. Can you edit to include a full citation & a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/332801)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the iformation! I edited my answer and added the quotes as well as the article citation.